# Elevation graph from GPX file

Tags: elevation, gpx, graph

I've got many GPX files in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.1" creator="c174a4ce-d611-43ef-b4d9-e4122bc8f2a4" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <rte>
    <name>Withens Clough, Cragg Vale and Stoodley Pike</name>
    <rtept lat="53.705918666306154" lon="-2.02137437495311">
      <ele>268</ele>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="53.705457119907116" lon="-2.0253609418514311">
      <ele>293.8</ele>
    </rtept>
    ....
  </rte>
</gpx>
```

I use this is a website to generate a route using [OS Openspace](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/web-services/os-openspace/api/index.html) maps. However, this doesn't create an elevation profile.

**Is there a web service or something I can run on my web server that can generate GPX elevation graphs for embedding into webpages?** My web server runs PHP.

I've found plenty of Google map ones but don't need the map, just the graph, but in the implementations I've looked at it seems like one depends on the other and don't want to compromise loading times by including two maps or remove the OS maps which are a lot better, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice **OpenSpace Example with Elevation graph displayed** that uploads gpx files for anywhere in the UK and displays the Elevation.

http://www.maptogps.com/index.php

Altitude data from GeoNames http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

(its worth looking a the code and contacting the author via the feedback form)

Comment: Wow, that's a very nice implementation indeed, just what I'm after. I'd been playing with the OS's own 'panorama' data but I'll have a good look at what has been done on that site with different data. Great. Thanks!

Comment: panorama is not updated any more 'Update frequency: Unmaintained.' http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/land-form-panorama/index.html it is not complete in mountainous areas either.

Comment: mapstogps.com is no longer in service, apparently.